# OCaml Unbound value List.assoc

Tags: ocaml

I'm compiling a module with a function that calls List.assoc, it fails to build giving me "Unbound value List.assoc" ... i've tried other List functions and they work fine, it also works fine in utop.

I can reproduce this by compiling an ml file using corebuild and this code

```
open Core.Std

let p = [(1,2);(2,3);(3,4)]
in List.assoc 2 p
```

Here is my build command:

```
$ corebuild blah.byte + ocamlfind ocamlc -c -w A-4-33-40-41-42-43-34-44 -strict-sequence -g -bin-annot -short-paths -thread -syntax camlp4o -package bin_prot.syntax -package sexplib.syntax,comparelib.syntax,fieldslib.syntax,variantslib.syntax -package core -o blah.cmo blah.ml
File "blah.ml", line 5, characters 3-13: Error: Unbound value List.assoc Command exited with code 2.
```

Comment: What is your build command?

Comment: $ corebuild blah.byte

+ ocamlfind ocamlc -c -w A-4-33-40-41-42-43-34-44 -strict-sequence -g -bin-annot -short-paths -thread -syntax camlp4o -package bin_prot.syntax -package sexplib.syntax,comparelib.syntax,fieldslib.syntax,variantslib.syntax -package core -o blah.cmo blah.ml
File "blah.ml", line 5, characters 3-13:
Error: Unbound value List.assoc
Command exited with code 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Core library replaces the standard OCaml `List` module.  When you `open Core.Std` you mask OCaml's standard `List` with Core's `Core.Std.List` module.  The `Core.Std.List.assoc` function does not exist.  If you aren't opening `Core.Std` in utop then you're most likely still working with OCaml's standard library `List` module.

Core does provide a replacement for this functionality with `List.Assoc`.  You can see some documentation here: https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core_kernel.112.17.00/_build/lib/core_list/#/module:Assoc

`List.Assoc.find_exn` looks like it is a replacement for the stdlib's `List.assoc`.

Answer (score 0):

The API has changed to:

```
List.assoc 1 p
```

see this:
http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html